# Sqoop export columns

Tags: sql-server, sqoop

Do we need to give SQL column names only in order of HDFS columns?

*Example:*
We update SQL table in the following format:

```
sqoop export 
--connect "jdbc:sqlserver://blah;database=blahblah" 
--username="user" --password="pass" 
--driver "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver" 
--table "blahblhablha" --export-dir "/blah"
--columns "id,name,age" --update-key "id"
```

where my SQL table is in format:

```
+--+---+----+
|id|age|name|
+--+---+----+
```

while I'm executing above sqoop command it's running fine but freezes at 100% and never finishes the job.
Is it compulsory that columns should be in order?(I don't think so).
It's running fine when I give in same order `--columns "id,age,name"`
Is there something I'm missing here?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the order the data in HDFS is in. Let's use the following CSV data as an example:

```
1,55,"John Smith"
2,22,"Jason Jonas"
...
```

If the `--columns` argument is set to `id,name,age`, then Sqoop will create insert statements that take on the form `INSERT INTO blahblahblah (id, name, age) VALUES (1, 55, "John Smith")`. This should not work since `"John Smith"` is clearly not an integer. So, order matters here.

See [docs](http://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.4.5/SqoopUserGuide.html#_selecting_the_data_to_import) for more details and the [user@sqoop.apache.org](http://mailto:user@sqoop.apache.org) mailing list for more help.